# How do I create restricted users in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003

i have windows server 2003 and the workstation windows xp
I want to create a user that should NOT be able to do the following options 
1. the user should not view or change TCP/IP Properties
2. the user should not be allowed to install any new program to the machine.
3. the user should not be allowed to share his file
4. the user should not be allowed to uninstall any programs from the machine.

Thanks,
hossam

Comment: Do you have a domain?

Answer (score 1):

Those you described are standard permissions for non-admin users.

So, if you simply create an user account and ***not*** make it member of Domain Admins (if you have a domain) or local Administrators (on a single machine) groups, he will not be able to do anything you do not want him to.